# SSRS Report Server - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: http, reporting-services, report

At the company I work at we use an SSRS Report Server to publish financial reports and such. It always worked really well, but a couple of days ago, the server where the Report Server is running on was restarted due to a security update. The Report server doesn't work ever since.

When accessing the URL, I get the error message "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."
I checked the logs on the server and found the following error messages:

RSHostingService.log

```
INFO|4|Launching Process : Management Service
INFO|4|Starting Process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\Management\RSManagement.exe
WARN|12|Child Process [Management Service] Died. Check the log for further information
INFO|12|Immediate restart of process Management Service
```

RSManagement.log

```
ERROR|1|Unhandled exception in Appdomain System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, Func2 appFunc, IList1 addresses, IDictionary2 capabilities, Func2 loggerFactory)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(Func2 app, IDictionary2 properties)
End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
at Microsoft.BIServer.Management.WebHost.Program.Main(), Exception RSManagement.exe: 
ERROR|1|Report server dump occurred: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException at 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
at Microsoft.BIServer.Management.WebHost.Program.Main()
```

Event Log 1:

```
Application: RSManagement.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.HttpListenerException
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(System.Net.HttpListener, System.Func2<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary2<System.String,System.Object>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, System.Collections.Generic.IList1<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary2<System.String,System.Object>>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary2<System.String,System.Object>, System.Func2<System.String,System.Func`6<System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType,Int32,System.Object,System.Exception,System.Func3<System.Object,System.Exception,System.String>,Boolean>>)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(System.Func2<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary2<System.String,System.Object>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>)
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(Owin.IAppBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext)
   at Microsoft.BIServer.Management.WebHost.Program.Main()
```

Event Log 2:

```
Faulting application name: RSManagement.exe, version: 15.0.1102.1002, time stamp: 0x63055c58
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17763.3887, time stamp: 0x3e07c6b6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00000000000349b9
Faulting process id: 0x3b94
Faulting application start time: 0x01d92b0c60e4aa6c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\Management\RSManagement.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 4b258278-3fbe-4e6c-bbc5-333482c6ba63
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Another thing I have noticed is that when I try to use the Report Server Config Tool, it takes an extremely long time to load. When the Report Server was working just fine, this was notthe case either.

I tried restarting the Reporting Server service numerous times, but that didn't change anything.
Since the RSManagement Service is mentioned in the error messages, I tried executing RSManagement.exe myself. That created the following log file:

```
    INFO|1|File Logger created: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\Management\RSManagement_2023_01_18_08_20_54.log - level Info, will roll at 32 Mb, process id 14868
INFO|1|No flag is configured for the Dumper. Using Default settings.
INFO|1|Do not dump on: 
ERROR|1|Unhandled exception in Appdomain System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Missing Configuration [listenerUrl]
   at Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment.StaticConfig.GetOrException(String key)
   at Microsoft.BIServer.Management.WebHost.Program.Main(), Exception RSManagement.exe: 
ERROR|1|Exception thrown while reading configuration: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Missing Configuration [rsConfigFilePath]
   at Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment.StaticConfig.GetOrException(String key)
   at Microsoft.BIServer.Configuration.ConfigReader.get_Current()System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Missing Configuration [rsConfigFilePath]
   at Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment.StaticConfig.GetOrException(String key)
   at Microsoft.BIServer.Configuration.ConfigReader.get_Current()
INFO|1|Logger shutting down
```

Lastly I tried completely uninstalling SSRS and reinstall it. After the reinstallation, the error message was the same. I assume that there is some external configuration that might be messing with the Report Server?
I also use a Power BI Report server running on the same server, which surprisingly woks. I also thought that maybe the PBI Report Server might cause a conflict, but I am not sure.

Comment: You probably need to post this on  one of the other exchange sites like Server Fault (https://serverfault.com) as this is not a programming related question.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port number for the site?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms and the actual error was a license error.

I was using the evaluation version and it had expired